# PowerShell SharePoint online ISE IntelliSense

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365

I want to write PowerShell for SharePoint online using [ISE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315244.aspx), but I can't seem to be able to make it use the intellisense for the object. When I run the

```
Import-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Powershell -Verbose
```

it's giving me this error:

> The specified module 'Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Powershell' was not
>   loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to open ISE so it is running under an administrator account as well in order for it to import the module. The error you're seeing is a permission issue, and it happens even on the SharePoint online management shell when you don't run it as an administrator. You need to run ISE as an administrator too.

Comment: oops, you were right it's a security thing. thanks for your direction.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really have SharePoint Online Management Shell installed? That is what you need.

Download link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35588

Comment: Hi Robert, yes I have it, I open it using admin account, and connect with: connect-sposervice. It works 100%, but I want to use ISE (Integrated Scripting Environment), in order to get intellisense. using Import-Module isn't working. Any extra steps I need to do?

Comment: I think it might be so, check here: http://pcfromdc.blogspot.se/2013/08/powershell-for-sharepoint-in-o365.html if it helps you out